# Getting Request Entity Too Large error 413 while sending attachment over 5 MB size using Gmail API in php

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

Error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception:  
>   Request Entity Too Large
>
> ## Request Entity Too Large
>
> ### Error 413
>
> in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176):
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(798):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...', Array) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php
>   on line 118
>
> Code :$strRawMessage .= 'To: ' . encodeRecipients(" <" . $strToMail .
>   ">") . "\r\n";    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' .
>   base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";    $strRawMessage .=
>   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  $strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: resumable;
>   boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";   $strRawMessage .=
>   'Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked' . "\r\n\r\n";
>
> /*************Attachment**************/     $basename =
>   basename($filePath);  $fileTempPath = sys_get_temp_dir() . "/" .
>   $basename;    file_put_contents($fileTempPath,
>   file_get_contents($filePath));    $finfo =
>   finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype
>   extension     $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $fileTempPath);  $fileData =
>   base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileTempPath));  $strRawMessage .=
>   "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";  $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: ' .
>   $mimeType . '; name="' . $basename . '";' . "\r\n";   //$strRawMessage
>   .= 'Content-Type: message/rfc822 ' . "\r\n";  $strRawMessage .=
>   'Content-ID: <' . $basename . '>' . "\r\n";   $strRawMessage .=
>   'Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileTempPath) . "\r\n";    $strRawMessage
>   .= 'X-Upload-Content-Type: message/rfc822' . "\r\n";  $strRawMessage
>   .= 'X-Upload-Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileTempPath) . "\r\n";
>     $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: ' . $basename . ';' . "\r\n";
>     $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .
>   $basename . '"; size=' . filesize($fileTempPath) . ';' . "\r\n";
>     $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked' . "\r\n\r\n";
>     $strRawMessage .= chunk_split($fileData, 76, "\r\n") . "\r\n";
>     $strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";

```
/*************Attachment**************/

$strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
//$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $strMessage . "\r\n";
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$message->setRaw($mime);
$messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message, ['uploadType' => 'resumable ']);
```